# Old functions return 'undefined' error once I add a jquery reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Disregard this question: I've simply confused `<script src="..."></script>` tag and `<script> [some functions] </scipt>` tags.

I have this function

```
function OnLoad()
{
    ShowHideConfirmAnswers();

    return true;
}
```

triggered by onload event:

```
<body onload=OnLoad()>
```

It works fine until I add src="jquery-1.4.2.js" to the script element. From this moment I get "OnLoad is not defined" error, and the same happens to every other javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine until I add src="jquery-1.4.2.js" to the script element.

This line makes me think you're using a script element like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //... all code here
</script>
```

And then you're adding the `src` attribute to the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js">
    //... all code here
</script>
```

Which won't work.  Once you add the `src` attribute to a `<script>` element, all data contained within the script element will be completely ignored by the browser.  You have to use separate script tags for external and inline javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //... all code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the OnLoad call to this script block ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ShowHideConfirmAnswers();
}
```

And just remove the OnLoad="" block from the Html.

Comment: Also, this approach encourages you to write your Javascript consistently.  You might even consider in-lining ShowHideConfirmAnswer().